# R: Getting around periodic random numbers

Tags: r, random

I'm building a distribution of proportions of random values lower than a specified threshold.

```r
ret = c(); thr = 0.5; n = 15; reps = 10000
for (x in 1:reps) {
  prop = sum(runif(n, 0, 1) < thr) / n
  ret = c(ret, prop)
}
plot(density(ret), main=NA)
```

The resulting density distribution is highly periodic and is not something one would theoretically expect:

[image]

I presume this has something to do with the periodicity of the random number generator. Is there any way around this?

Comment: The `periodicity` is just an illusion. Since you set `n=15`, `ret` can be, as it is defined, any value between `0/15` and `14/15`, with a `1/15` step. See `sort(unique(ret)*15)` and try `plot(table(ret))`.

Comment: You have 16 possible values of `ret`, corresponding to 16 peaks in your density

Comment: If you print `ret` you will see many 0.3333, 0.6666, etc. This is because the samples are small (15 elems) and 15 = 3*5. The proportions will be very, very, regular, leaving holes in the histogram. Try `hist(ret)` to see it.

Comment: Like @HongOoi says, there are a total of 16 values returned by `table(ret)`. Try plotting `barplot(table(ret))` for a better visualization of your data.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I tend to prefer the output of `plot(table`, I think this is due to highlighting the discrete nature of the distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your distribution is discrete, and hence a kernel density estimate isn't the right tool.  Instead you should be plotting the frequencies, as indicated by @nicola and other commenters.

i.e.

```
plot(table(ret))
```

gives:

[image: plot]

Or, if you want probabilities, you could do:

```
plot(table(ret) / length(ret))
```

Comment: I only now realized this was a really silly question. With n=15 of course I get a painfully discreet distribution. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @themeo easy to do!  also note that these are basically just binomial samples, `rbinom(10000, 15, 0.5) / 15` will give you samples from the same distribution as `ret`